# How to log off from ask ubuntu website?

Tags: support, login

Once I'm logged into the ask ubuntu site, it seems there is no way to logoff short of exiting my browser.  If it is indeed possible to log off, I'd sure like to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222556/how-to-log-out-of-a-stack-exchange-site for the step-by-step video.

- Look in the top bar, right-most icon ("A list of all 176 Stack Exchange Sites"). It's in there.

Comment: Well blow me down with a feather... I never considered clicking the 'A list of all 176 SE sites' because the last thing I want to see is a list of all 176 sites.  So of course that's where it is.